# 404 Page wont show / no .htaccess Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to show my 404 error page when ever someone gets on a non working / non created page. After a long time of searching on the web I couldnt find any solution so I post one myself. I dont have any .htaccess file either i created it filled it in but in my FTP it kept saying nothing was safed in there and it didnt show any bytes so thats something im also worried of.

So how can i get my .htaccess file to work and show my 404 Error page template? I followed all the steps to make a 404.php file but i dont mind it to be redirected to the same template I made for it but then as a page any of those solutions is fine.

Comment: Have you tried `ErrorDocument 404 /path/to/404.html` in the .htaccess file; assuming your server is allowing you to upload one... which seems problematic from what you've said? An .htaccess file is simply a text file, called *.htaccess* - nothing more really, you shouldn't have any problems making one... http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument

Comment: not exactly with that many slashes but yes i did that and didnt do anything plus i dont think i can get my .htaccess file to work at all

Comment: Got some progress in it but got an error 500 now

Comment: Sounds like a syntax error in the .htaccess doc - that'll trigger an internal server error...

Comment: `# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
ErrorDocument 404 /httpdocs/wp-content/themes/avian/404.php
</IfModule>
# END WordPress` is my .htaccess

Comment: and this is what it shows: http://www.viscongroup.eu/index.php/fdsaf

Comment: Ah - that set of Rewrites (`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` ... etc) redirects to the homepage if the requested resource is neither a file (`-f`) nor a directory (`-d`) - that's preventing your `ErrorDocument` from ever getting called... technically there can never *really* be a 404 error with that setup.

Comment: well how do i have to do my .htacces then just picked the basic wp one and the index.php in all my url's also annoys me how to fix both of them pretty clueless at the moment :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got some rewrite rules in your .htaccess file that are preventing a 404 error from every truly happening...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

That basically states that if the requested resource is neither a file nor a directory (basically a 404 error), redirect to **/index.php**

Try this in your .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 

# delete the line below to have /index.php/anything trigger a 404
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 

</IfModule> 
# END WordPress

#404 redirect
ErrorDocument 404 /httpdocs/wp-content/themes/avian/404.php
```

**Note**
This *may* make Wordpress quite unhappy however, I'm not sure how it uses internal routing, it may rely on breaking 404s to determine which pages to load by using fake (RESTful) URLs - reinstating 404 errors make cause Wordpress to stop working properly ... I am, however, no expert on it having barely ever touched it.

Comment: Are you still getting a `500` error ... if so it's possible the path to the 404 doc is wrong (which would cause a 404 error ... which would cause a 404 error ... ad inifinitum) so it goes to a `500` error.

Comment: There's still a rewrite in there so that `/index.php` will redirect and not 404 irrespective of what's after the `/index.php/...` - if you want to switch that off as well - delete the line `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]` from the .htaccess file. URLs like `viscongroup.eu/badgerbagdgerbadger` should 404 at the moment.